# Estimate the order of recursive series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the following series generated by recursive function:
$$a_{n+1}=\sin a_n$$

Apparently, $a_n$ is infinitesimal.

Apply **Stolz Theorem** to $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{1/a_n}$, we can get:
$$a_n\sim\sqrt{\frac{1}{3n}}$$

If we want to estimate it more accurately, such as: **(This result is only for clearer description, not correct)**
$$a_n=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3n}}+\frac1n\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}+o\left(\frac1n\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$$

The step (Stolz) cannot continue.

What other methods can be used for this issue?

Comment: What is $a_0$ ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837335/proving-the-limiting-behavior-of-functions-containing-iterated-trigonometric-fun and any other of the many questions towards the "sine iteration". https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449281/iterated-sine-function-on-different-arguments looks nice too

Comment: The next terms in $\frac3{a_n^2}-\frac3{a_0^2}=n+...$ are constant and logarithmic in some complicated way, thus seldom explored.